# pause system functionality until my python script is done

Tags: python, linux, passwords

I have written a simple python script that runs as soon as a certain user on my linux system logs in. It ask's for a password... however the problem is they just exit out of the terminal or minimize it and continue using the computer. So basically it is a password authentication script. So what I am curious about is how to make the python script stay up and not let them exit or do anything else until they entered the correct password. Is there some module I need to import or some command that can pause the system functions until my python script is done?

Thanks

I am doing it just out of interest and I know a lot could go wrong but I think it would be a fun thing to do. It can even protect 1 specific system process. I am just curious how to pause the system and make the user do the python script before anything else.

Comment: You know the Linux OS can assign users a password?

Comment: This sounds like a horrible idea, why don't you just use the OS implementation? Better yet insist on RSA key authentication. (okay horrible is a bit OTT but there's just _so_ many things that can go wrong).

Comment: Which resources is this password protecting? The access to the system itself? In other words, if the user has already been authenticated by the OS, why do you need another authentication before they can access the whole system? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this thing is just for fun, here's a work arond: make the script log the user out if he ignores the prompt for some time, or closes the terminal/kills the process. Here's how it might look like for gnome:

```
import os

def set_exit_handler(func):
    import signal
    signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, func) # on closing the terminal
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, func) # on killing the process

    import atexit
    atexit.register(func) # on Ctrl-C, Ctrl-D and other proper exits

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def on_exit(a=None, b=None):
        print "exit handler triggered"
        os.system("gnome-session-quit --logout --no-prompt")
    set_exit_handler(on_exit)

    print "Enter password:"
    raw_input()
    # ... some verification/timeout code ...
```

If the user will now close the terminal or kill the process, he'll be logged out instantaneously :)

Answer (score 3):

There will always be a way for the user to get past your script.

Let's assume for a moment that you actually manage to block the X-server, without blocking input to your program (so the user can still enter the password). The user could just alt-f1 out of the X-server to a console and kill "your weird app". If you manage to block that too he could ssh to the box and kill your app.

There is most certainly no generic way to do something like this; this is what the login commands for the console and the session managers (like gdm) for the graphical display are for: they require a user to enter his password before giving him some form of interactive session. After that, why would you want yet another password to do the same thing? the system is designed to not let users use it without a password (or another form of authentication), but there is no API to let programs block the system whenever they feel like it.

Answer (score 2):

You want the equivalent of a "modal" window, but this is not (directly) possible in a multiuser, multitasking environment.

The next best thing is to prevent the user from *accessing* the system. For example, if you create an invisible window as large as the display, that will intercept any mouse events, and whatever is "behind" will be unaccessible.

At that point you have the problem of preventing the user from using the keyboard to terminate the application, or to switch to another application, or to another virtual console (this last is maybe the most difficult). So you need to access and lock the keyboard, not only the "standard" keyboard but the low-level keys as well.

And to do this, your application needs to have administrative rights, and yet run in the user environment. Which starts to look like a recipe for disaster, unless you *really* know what you are doing.

What you want to do should be done through a Pluggable Authentication Module (PAM) that will integrate with your display manager. Maybe, you can find some PAM module that will "outsource" or "callback" some external program, i.e., your Python script.